# yfinance not working - receiving json.decoder.JSONDecodeError

Tags: python, api, yahoo, yfinance

I am scraping stock market data from yfinance. My code worked perfectly during the last weeks. For some reason, now I am receiving the following error:

> json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

when executing:

```
import yfinance as yf
tsla_df = yf.download('TSLA', start='2020-01-01', end='2021-01-01', progress=False)
```

I have read about this error on Stack Overflow, but no one had an appropriate solution to fix the problem. I am wondering because this simple code worked well days ago. So maybe there is a general problem with the yfinance API at the moment? Can anyone confirm or has a solution for this problem?

Comment: Getting this same error just starting today

Comment: known issue, links in answer.  great time to check prices unless you are short!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Issue has been raised with yfinance, you need to upgrade

Follow here

https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance/issues/764

from github:

> If you're getting an json.decoder.JSONDecodeError related error, please upgrade to yfinance 0.1.62.
> Upgrade using:

> $ pip install yfinance -U--no-cache-dir

Full conversation here :
https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance/issues/760

I couldn't get the fix to work but this comment worked for me
https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance/issues/760#issuecomment-877379498

```
pip uninstall yfinance
pip install git+https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance.git#egg=yfinance
```

Comment: you are my hero!

Comment: pip install --upgrade yfinance    <-- worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Checked out https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance/issues/764 and his suggestion didn't work for me but I got it done with

"pip install --upgrade yfinance"

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
pip uninstall yfinance
pip uninstall pandas-datareader
pip install yfinance --upgrade --no-cache-dir
pip install pandas-datareader
```