# Python YFinance json.decoder.JSONDecodeError

Tags: python, json, yfinance

I've been using Yfinance to download and analyze historic data for a few months now. I noticed recently that when I try to download historic data, I get the following error message:

[image: Error message]

[image: Second part of error message]

I couldn't get the script above to work at all until I referenced this source: [yfinance not working - receiving json.decoder.JSONDecodeError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68321311/yfinance-not-working-receiving-json-decoder-jsondecodeerror)

But even after updating yfinance and pandas_datareader, I am still getting the json decode error. If I run the script with only 50 tickers, I don't end up getting any error and it works fine, but when I try to run it on ~2000 tickers, it fails. So I wonder if it has something to do with too many requests?

Also, if I continue to let it run despite the error messages, it stops at 99% and won't finish:
[image: If I let it run despite errors]

Full script:

```
import datetime
start = datetime.datetime(2021,7,10)
end = datetime.datetime(2021,8,5)
#Short list of tickers, usually around 2000 here. 
schwab_list = ['MX', 'ADVM', 'TALO', 'DAC', 'SIL', 'AGRO', 'CRIS', 'AMRX', 'STNG', 'HUTMF']
import yfinance as yf
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr, wb
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random



# for scraping faster

yf.pdr_override() # <== that's all it takes :-)

sample = yf.download(schwab_list, start=start, end=end, threads=True)
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: This may be better of as a bug report. For a question here, you'd have to extract and provide a [mcve]. BTW: Don't use images of text, they can't be indexed easily so that they can be found during a search.

Comment: ok thanks - I'll look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade to version 0.1.63 using:

pip install yfinance --upgrade --no-cache-dir